# Applying a input mask in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin, input-mask

I'm learning Rails and i'm building an admin api for my project. There's a _form.html.erb on views that i need to mask some field inputs like this one:

```
<div class="field">
  <%= form.label :cnpj %>
  <%= form.text_field :cnpj %>
</div>
```

Input value: 12345678000123 
Display value during input: 12.345.678/0001-23

I have found some solutions involving js and jquery plugins, but i didn't manage to work them out (because i'm not familiar with using js/jquery plugins). What is the best way to mask these fields?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "mask"? Do you want to hide the inputs or disable them?

Comment: I think he needs to show a format for users, eg _ _ _ - _ _ _  - _ _ _ _ for a phone number, and the _ will disappear as they type in. He can probably pull html5 input + pattern matching + placeholders.

Comment: As NickM said, i need to format the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to be using Javascript for that (vanilla, jQuery, Angular, React, etc).  There are various ways to pull in a library/framework.

if the model you're using is Company then the form element Id will be '`company_cnpj`'

Your element will render as

```
<input type="text" name="company[cnpj]" id="company_cnpj">
```

Depending on the library used, you can setup a basic mask with:

```
$(function() {
  $('#company_cnpj').inputmask({ mask: "(123) 456-7890" });
});
```

https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask gives you the option to pass in regex directly via a data attributes.